# How can I make npm start open into a different browser

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npm-start

On my pc the default browser is Firefox but I want to open my react projects on Chrome. I tried changing the script in `package.json` as `"start": "BROWSER=chrome react-scripts start"`.
I also tried putting chrome inside single quotes. I even tried creating a .env file as `BROWSER=<my chrome path>` and modified the `package.json` script to `"start": "env-cmd react-scripts start"`.
I have also tried installing **cross-env** and using it. But none of this worked and `npm start` still opens a tab in Firefox. How can i fix this issue?
React version: 18.2.0
OS: Windows 11

Comment: What is your OS?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to override your default browser:
navigate to `package.json`
Replace: `"start": "react-scripts start"`
to: `"start": "BROWSER='google-chrome-stable' react-scripts start"`
for **Linux** like myself.
and `"start": "BROWSER='chrome' react-scripts start"` for **windows** and `"start": "BROWSER='google chrome' react-scripts start"` for **OSx**. Note that there is a "`,`".

if it works, there will be a response in the terminal.

```
you@you:~/Your folder/your-app$ yarn start yarn run v1.22.19 $BROWSER='google-chrome-stable' react-scripts start
```

[Terminal response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmcXw.png)

else: Run `npm install --save-dev cross-env` this is an npm install for [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) since `BROWSER` is an environment variable. Then navigate to `package.json` and edit `"start": "BROWSER='google-chrome-stable' react-scripts start"` to `"start": "cross-env BROWSER=chrome react-scripts start"` like so. Else: always run `BROWSER=chrome npm start` in place of `npm start`  or simply open `localhost:3000` or your current port on google chrome as long as the development server is running. All the best.

**Else.....**
To set the default browser for your React projects in Visual Studio Code, you can try the following steps:

Open Visual Studio Code and go to the terminal.

In the terminal, enter the following command to install the open package, which allows you to specify the default browser for your React projects:

```
npm install open
```

In the package.json file, update the start script to use the open package to open your React project in the desired browser, like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "open -a /Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app -- react-scripts start"
}
```

Replace /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app with the path to the Chrome executable on your system. You can find this by opening Chrome, going to the menu, and selecting "About Google Chrome".

Save the changes to package.json and run the npm start command in the terminal. This should open a new tab in Chrome with your React project.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This gives an error in terminal stating 'BROWSER is not recognized as an internal or external command'.

Comment: try upgrading your react version.

Comment: I tried and it makes no difference at all